# how to consume a web service in mule flow?

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, mule, jax-ws

I am beginning with Mule flows. I am trying to consume a webservice in it.
But I am getting some some errors while running.

> Error reported by XML parser: Content is not allowed in prolog

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8095" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" wsdlLocation="MSCRMDiscoveryService_WSDL.wsdl" service="DiscoveryService" port="CustomBinding_IDiscoveryService" serviceAddress="https://disco.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <data-mapper:config name="Xml_ExecuteResponse__To_Xml_Execute_" transformationGraphPath="xml_executeresponse__to_xml_execute_.grf" doc:name="Xml_ExecuteResponse__To_Xml_Execute_"/>
    <data-mapper:config name="Xml_ExecuteResponse__To_Xml_Execute__1" transformationGraphPath="xml_executeresponse__to_xml_execute__1.grf" doc:name="Xml_ExecuteResponse__To_Xml_Execute__1"/>
    <flow name="mscrmdiscoveryservice-consumerFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Xml_ExecuteResponse__To_Xml_Execute_" doc:name="Xml&lt;ExecuteResponse&gt; To Xml&lt;Execute&gt;"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="Execute" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="Xml_ExecuteResponse__To_Xml_Execute__1" doc:name="Xml&lt;ExecuteResponse&gt; To Xml&lt;Execute&gt;"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

wsdl file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://example.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="HelloWorldService" targetNamespace="http://example.org/">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://example.org/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://example.org/" version="1.0">
<xs:element name="sayHi" type="tns:sayHi"/>
<xs:element name="sayHiResponse" type="tns:sayHiResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="sayHi">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="sayHiResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="sayHi">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:sayHi" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="sayHiResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:sayHiResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="HelloWorld">
    <wsdl:operation name="sayHi">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:sayHi" name="sayHi">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:sayHiResponse" name="sayHiResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="HelloWorldServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:HelloWorld">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="sayHi">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="sayHi">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="sayHiResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="HelloWorldService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:HelloWorldServiceSoapBinding" name="HelloWorldPort">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8085/hello"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Tidied up question for readability.

Comment: 'Content is not allowed in prolog':  Denotes some problem in xml structure, not a valid xml (May in the input xml which you are giving or inbetween).

Comment: What do you do in the `data-mapper` transfos? It's impossible to tell from the config you've shared.

Answer (score 0):

From the flow you shared, is difficult to tell where the error exactly exists ... It may be your from your wrong XML structure.
Also not clear the use of Datamapper in consuming external web service
The easiest way to consume an existing web service from Mule flow is to prepare/build the soap request for the external service using set payload or XSLT transformer, and then dispatch it through HTTP outbound or HTTP request component.